# Can FIWARE context providers be used for historical data with QuantumLeap?

Tags: proxy, time-series, fiware, cratedb

FIWARE offers using context providers to fetch data from external sources for entities that are queried through the context broker.

With QuantumLeap, historical data can be stored in a time series database such as CrateDB.

Is it possible to combine these two concepts? When querying for historical data in a QuantumLeap setup, could some data instead be fetched from another database via a registered context provider (or a similar proxy implementation)? Preferably using out-of-the-box FIWARE components without too much custom magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can always send the information to the QuantumLeap using the proper protocol. For this purpose, inside the FIWARE Ecosystem we have defined the IoT Agents to translate the common transport protocols and payload formats towards NGSI protocol. Additionally, there is other component, FIWARE Draco that could be used in order to translate the information from one DB to other. In case of QuantumLeap, and also any other FIWARE component, the normal way of working is through subscription to the source of data and this is the major reason why we put always in the architectures the FIWARE Orion Context Broker, whose purpose is to notify subscribers any update in the context information.